# onClick event does not have the latest props of the Marker

Tags: react-leaflet

The onClick event contains details about the Marker who was clicked. However, I have noticed that if I update a prop on the Marker, and then click it, `event.target.options` which appears to be the props, does not contain the updated prop.

I have found that if I update the prop AND change the key, then the onClick event will have the updated prop; however, then my PopUp breaks probably due to the component being redrawn and the popup state getting reset from the new key.

Please let me know if you need additional clarification or details.

Comment: Interestingly, when I use React Developer Tools to look at the Marker after the prop has changed, it has the latest prop! But then I click it, look at the event, and the prop is not the updated one...

Comment: I ran into the same issue, seems like it's not rerendering the map properly. 
Finally I have fixed that using the props as refs instead of state. So the props can be mutated and will change at the same time in the map. Here you can find some further informations: https://cherniavskii.com/using-leaflet-in-react-apps-with-react-hooks/